# R starting and stopping a shiny app via cmd / shell

Tags: r, shiny

I start a shiny app from my main R script using

```
system("R -e shiny::runApp(launch.browser=T,port=5000)", wait=F)
```

How can I later on stop this app from the same main R script? I tried both

```
shiny::stopApp()
system("R -e shiny::stopApp()")
```

Without success (hanging)

Comment: perhaps I should get a PID or something ?

Comment: "It's messy" as you are now entering process and state management for which R isn't really built.  Depending on the OS you are on, different helpers may be available.  And Gabor et al have built some helper packages for this situation so fetching process id for the custom R process you launch and killing it may work.  I find relying on the OS easier and tend to run `shiny-server` when I need it...

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on Windows based on the port number

```
# start demo UI ----------------------------------------------------------------
library(dplyr)
log_info("starting demo app")
shell("R -e shiny::runApp(launch.browser=T,port=5000)", wait=F)

# mingle with your app here

log_info("quitting demo app")
netstat <- system("netstat -ano", intern = T)
ns <- netstat[grepl("127.0.0.1:5000",netstat)] %>% strsplit(" ") 
ns <- lapply(ns, function(x) x[x!=""]) 
ns <- suppressMessages(sapply(ns, rbind) %>% t %>% as_tibble(.name_repair = "unique"))
pids <- ns[,5] %>% unique %>% as.data.frame() %>% unlist()

sapply(pids, function(i) system(paste0("taskkill /F /PID ",i)))
```

To fully quit chrome:

```
system("taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T")
```